# How to access a nested structure using PyADS

Tags: plc, twincat, structured-text, twincat-ads

I have two structures defined in TwinCAT3 like so:

```
TYPE ADSUWDisplay :
STRUCT
    sYarn : STRING;
    sNextYarn : STRING;
    lLength : REAL;
    iPosition : INT;
    sYarnSpec : STRING;
    iPackageCount : INT;
    iPackageTotalCount : INT;
    iCount : INT;
    iTotalCount : INT;
    sUpcomingYarn : STRING;
    sUpcomingYarnSpec : STRING;
    sUWMessage : STRING;
    sThreadUp : STRING;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

TYPE ADSRemoteDisplay :
STRUCT
    iUW : INT;
    iCount : INT;
    sState : STRING
    iStateNo : INT;
    sRobotMessage : STRING;
    adsUWDisplay : ARRAY[0..5] OF ADSUWDisplay;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

As you can see, ADSUWDisplay is nested inside ADSRemoteDisplay.

How can I access ADSUWDisplay using PyADS?

More specifically, how do I declare my Structure defs for use in pyads.connection.read_structure_by_name()?

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read out a struct as follows, from the [pyads docs](https://pyads.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation/symbols.html#symbol-creation):

> Use the parameter `structure_def` to define the structure and `array_size` to define the size of the array.

```
 >>> structure_def = (
         ("i", pyads.PLCTYPE_INT, 1),
         ("s", pyads.PLCTYPE_STRING, 1)
     )
 >>> symbol = plc.get_symbol("MyStructure", structure_def=structure_def, array_size=2)
 >>> symbol.write([{"i": 1, " "s": "foo"}, {"i": 2, "s": "bar"}])
 >>> symbol.read()
[{"i": 1, " "s": "foo"}, {"i": 2, "s": "bar"}]
```

Not sure how to define a nested struct. I guess you can try to add a nested tuple in `structure_def`, e.g.:

```
structure_def = (
         ("i", pyads.PLCTYPE_INT, 1),
         (
             ("s1", pyads.PLCTYPE_STRING, 1),
             ("s2", pyads.PLCTYPE_STRING, 1)
         )
     )
```